# How to change the Progress Spinner in ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am having an Material ProgressBar library which I want to integrate in a `ProgressDialog`. How to do it?

I only want to change the `Loader`/`Spinner`, nothing else.

Comment: add the custom layout to progress dialog and use the some custom progress bar in layout...... what you want....

Comment: How to add a layout? I have a material progressbar lib..

Comment: Use the `setIndeterminateDrawable()` method of `ProgressDialog` to set your custom `Drawable`.

Comment: popupDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.MyDialog);
popupDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);

Comment: @user6819340 used the    pb.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressbar); here in custom_progressbar you can take custom bar check more example you find with custom progess bar or  custom Drawable. you use as user13 say

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
     progressDoalog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
       // progressDoalog.setMax(100);
       // progressDoalog.setMessage("Loading Content......");
        progressDoalog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDoalog.setTitle("Loading Content ");
        progressDoalog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDoalog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDoalog.show();
```

Letme know if it helps

Comment: I don't need that.. :) I want to customize the ProgressBar